# Is `/tmp` the right place for UNIX-domain socket files?

Tags: sockets, unix

When using UNIX sockets for IPC communication, a file must be created in the file system. Many examples out there on the Internet suggest `/tmp` as a good place to place sockets in. Some suggest to use `/tmp/specific_folder` with `700` permissions to keep `/tmp` clean and the sockets safe from other users access.

However, is that reliable? Can't the OS remove any file in there at any moment? Let us suppose those files are to persist in there for days or months and some might not be used for communication during long periods (i.e.: days).

Also, storing those files in a local user folder (for example, in `./.hidden_sockets/`) has the disadvantage of not cleaning those files in case, for example, the system crashes. Not even after system reboot.

Where would you put those files? Is there a standard/preferred way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly the best place is a sub-directory beneath **[$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)**, where unprivileged user software can store runtime data such as communication primitives. This is similar to /run but for user applications. It's a user private namespace, and hence very safe to use. It's cleaned up automatically at logout. Sticky bit prevents files to be cleaned-up by time via "aging".

## Sources

- http://0pointer.net/blog/projects/tmp.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard
- https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html*

Answer (score 0):

When sticky bit is set on a folder then only the owner of the file and root can remove the file from that directory and by default /tmp directory is protected with sticky bit.
That is why it is suggested to put the socket file in /tmp folder so that only the owner and root have the permission to remove it but everyone can access it.

```
drwxrwxrwt. 25 root root 720 Mar 30 23:36 /tmp/
---------^--
this t indicate sticky bit ###this 1 in "chmod 1777 dir" used to set sticky bit
```

For complete story check the below step by step commands - 
Consider we have 3 users root, a and b.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mkdir /test     
[root@localhost ~]# chmod 777 /test/ 
[root@localhost ~]# su - a 
[a@localhost ~]$ cd /test/ 
[a@localhost test]$ touch a.txt 
[a@localhost test]$ ls -ltr a.txt 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 a a 0 Mar 30 17:25 a.txt 
[a@localhost test]$ su - b 
[b@localhost ~]$ cd /test/ 
[b@localhost test]$ touch b.txt 
[b@localhost test]$ rm a.txt 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'a.txt'? y 
[b@localhost test]$ su - a 
[a@localhost ~]$ cd /test/ 
[a@localhost test]$ ll 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 b b 0 Mar 30 17:25 b.txt 
[a@localhost test]$ rm b.txt 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'b.txt'? y 
[a@localhost test]$ su - root 
[root@localhost ~]# chmod 1777 /test/ ####setting sticky bit
[root@localhost ~]# cd /test/ 
[root@localhost test]# su a 
[a@localhost test]$ pwd 
/test 
[a@localhost test]$ touch a.txt 
[a@localhost test]$ ll 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 a a 0 Mar 30 17:27 a.txt 
[root@localhost test]# su b 
[b@localhost test]$ touch b.txt 
[b@localhost test]$ ll 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 a a 0 Mar 30 17:27 a.txt 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 b b 0 Mar 30 17:27 b.txt 
[b@localhost test]$ rm a.txt  
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'a.txt'? y 
rm: cannot remove 'a.txt': Operation not permitted
```

> (b user is not able to remove the file because we have set the sticky
>   bit on the directory test)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I miss something in your answer when referring to the `/tmp` directory: *[...] is that reliable? Can't the OS remove any file in there at any moment? [...]* Basically, is there a 100% guarantee that the file will not be removed while in use? (even when the sockets are not sending messages for long periods of time)